# In what order should I watch Afro Samurai?

Tags: afro-samurai

Should I watch the movie first or the start with the first season?

And if I start with first season then should I watch the movie and then the resurrection?

Please tell me what should I watch, in what order and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Afro Samurai movie is basically the summary of what happens in the first season with a flashback of young Afro, whereas Afro Samurai season 2 is a sequel to both.

Hence, the recommended order of watching is:

1. Afro Samurai
2. Afro Samurai: The Movie
3. Afro Samurai Season 2

Comment: By season 2 you mean Resurrection? Right?

Comment: @abhishah901 Yeah